# Hello world with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-expressions

I am trying to get to grips with Expression Trees. I thought I'd start by writing a simple `helloWorld` function that creates a `StringBuilder`, appends `"Helloworld"`, and then outputs the string. This is what I have so far:

```
var stringBuilderParam = Expression.Variable
    typeof(StringBuilder), "sb");

var helloWorldBlock =
    Expression.Block( new Expression[]
        {
            Expression.Assign(
                stringBuilderParam, 
                Expression.New(typeof(StringBuilder))),
            Expression.Call(
                stringBuilderParam,
                typeof(StringBuilder).GetMethod(
                    "Append",
                    new[] { typeof(string) }),
                new Expression[]
                    {
                        Expression.Constant(
                            "Helloworld", typeof(string))
                    }),
            Expression.Call(
                stringBuilderParam,
                "ToString",
                new Type[0],
                new Expression[0])
        });

var helloWorld = Expression.Lamda<Func<string>>(helloWorldBlock).Compile();

Console.WriteLine(helloWorld);
Console.WriteLine(helloWorld());
Console.ReadKey();
```

The `Compile()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`

> variable 'sb' of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Obviously I'm not going about this the right way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

Obviously, I realise doing `Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld");` would be somewhat simpler.

Comment: I tried to cut and paste your code but there more compiler errors. Is there any more code to this that you can post?

Comment: @IanO'Brien, its likely that I've transcribed the code incorrectly. What compiler error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify variables for `BlockExpression` in order to use them. Just call [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324074.aspx):

```
var helloWorldBlock =
    Expression.Block(
        new ParameterExpression[] {stringBuilderParam},
        new Expression[]
            {
                Expression.Assign(
                    stringBuilderParam,
                    Expression.New(typeof (StringBuilder))),
                Expression.Call(
                    stringBuilderParam,
                    typeof (StringBuilder).GetMethod(
                        "Append",
                        new[] {typeof (string)}),
                    new Expression[]
                        {
                            Expression.Constant(
                                "Helloworld", typeof (string))
                        }),
                Expression.Call(
                    stringBuilderParam,
                    "ToString",
                    new Type[0],
                    new Expression[0])
            });
```